# Does anyone experience Xcode build errors when compiling the phonetic demo app for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, phonertc

I have been working with the phonertc demo at https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc and am having trouble when I get to Xcode. I am using Xcode 6.1 when i follow the steps outlined

```
Valid Architectures => armv7

Build Active Architecture Only => No

Objective-C Bridging Header => [ProjectName]/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Bridging-Header.h

Runpath Search Paths => $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
```

Where I am struggling is where to find the Runpath Search Paths step. Google searching isn't yielding any direct results. Can anyone tell me where this entry is specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look under Build Settings -> Linking.  See the images below:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you that did it! Oddly can't use the same method to find Objective-C Bridging Header